# Facebook Connect SDK with armv7 Architecture? :(

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, armv7, armv6

Recently built an iPad Application using the Facebook Connect SDK. It was recommended to me that i change the architecture of the project to armv6 to allow the Facebook Connect SDK to work.

After changing the project to armv6, it works fine on the simulator and device, however when i try to submit the application to iTunes Connect I receive the following error whilst submitting:

```
iPad: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7
```

So, I done some research and a simple alteration of the architecture (as follows) 'should' fix the problem:

[image]

However, the project fails to build with the following error(s):

```
ld: warning: ignoring file PROJECT/facebook-ios-sdk/build/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Objects-normal/armv6/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Someone correct me if i'm wrong, but it seems that iTunes Connect won't accept an iPad app binary *without* armv7, and the Facebook SDK won't allow the app to be build *with* armv7, right?

The only viable solution is enable the Facebook Connect SDK to be build with armv7 to which i've had no success with, i've read plenty of forums and posts that don't really come up with a solution that openly works.

I've been struggling on this for about 7 hours and i honestly don't know what else to do.

Has anybody submitted an iPad only app with the Facebook Connect SDK included? Would be interested to see what settings you have for your project.

Thanks guys, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for the new release of Facebook SDK, you can include the Facebook Source code in to the project then compile. It should work for armv7 architecture.